# When creating MediaWiki skins, are there files to change other than [SkinName].php and the [skinname] directory?

Tags: php, css, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am creating a MediaWiki skin based on an existing skin. Per suggestion from multiple sources(including MediaWiki documentation) I have copied an existing skin's .php file and its associated directory. In both file names and in the files themselves, I did a complete find and replace for all references to [previousskin] to [newskin], but when I try to preview the skin in my wiki, no styles at all are applied.

The skin is being instantiated, as I can select it in my appearance preferences, however I'm not sure why I am not seeing any styles.

I have tested multiple browsers, tried copying different default skins and renaming them as above but I can't seem to get any to show when renamed.

Am I missing any other files that need to be changed to reflect the new skin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out. Additional skins need the following:

`require_once( "$IP/skins/myskin/myskin.php" );`

in the LocalSettings.php file.